# How to create a right border that's only 70% of its actual size?

Tags: html, css

So, I have a sidebar on my site. It can vary dynamically in height. I want to have a 1px wide border to the right, but I don't want it to be as tall as the container; it should only be 70% that height. Also, it should be vertically centered to the middle of the container.

How can I do this? Most of the ways I've seen require the border's height to be defined, but I am not able to do that. Is this possible with just CSS? If not, how can I use JavaScript to perform this? Thanks!

Comment: What kind of browser support do you need?

Comment: Preferably all browsers, even IE.

Comment: How is you sidebar positioned (static, relative etc)? Is it of a fixed width?

Comment: well... every one beat me to it, but here's [my example](http://jsfiddle.net/Wa5X6/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got an idea, it's supported by `FF6` and `IE9` + `Chrome` and `Opera 11`:

**html**

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="border_r"></div>
    contents
</div>
```

**css**

```
#container {
    height: 356px;
    background: #eee;
    position: relative;
}
.border_r {
    border-right: 2px solid red;
    height: 70%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 15%;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SAu6Y/) ... I have no idea if it will work anywhere else

Comment: faster than me :P and yes this is cross-browser.  This is the way to do it. +1

Comment: very similar to my way, but mine uses `:before` to not add any more markup.

Comment: actually I think it would. :P The iffiest property would be position, but IE6 [only has issues with `position:fixed`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t28)

Comment: Err... this is nice and all, but you still need to define the container's height. I don't actually know my container's height. If worse comes to worse, I can just give it a large value, but for the time being, is there any way to do it dynamically?

Comment: @Jake King no, you don't. The height is only for the example. In your case I guess the container will be filled and it will work like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/SAu6Y/1/)

Comment: @Jake King. no you, don't have to define the height.  That's just there for convenience.  My solution is very similar but uses text to expand the container. [See here](http://jsfiddle.net/Wa5X6/)

Comment: @Joseph Ah, thank you for clarifying, I see now. I guess I'll accept this answer then.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a "pseudo-border" using [CSS Pseudo-elements](http://jsfiddle.net/4TnPJ/). Though [the browser support (particularly in the IE department) is not exactly stellar](http://css-tricks.com/9189-browser-support-pseudo-elements/), it's the more semantic (and recommended, if you can drop <IE7 support) way to do it.

Instead, if you don't mind the extra non-semantic element, you can simply do it [using an extra `<div>` inside of your sidebar](http://jsfiddle.net/4TnPJ/1/):

#### HTML

```
<div id="example-sidebar">
    <div id="example-border"></div>
    <ul>
        <li>a</li>
        <li>b</li>
        <li>c</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
#example-sidebar{
    background-color: yellow;
    color: black;
    height: 400px;
    margin-left: 1px;   /* Required for 70% height border */
    position: relative; /* Required for 70% height border */
    width: 150px;
}
#example-border{
    background-color: red;
    height: 70%;
    position: absolute;
        left: -1px;
        top: 15%;
    width: 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.box:before
{
    width: 1px;
    height: 70%;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    background-color: black;
    display: block;
    content: '';
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uxNar/